# Javascript play/pause toggle functionality

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add play/pause toggle functionality to a single button for an mp3 player project where the play button will turn to a "||" icon when music is playing and will revert to the play button when the music is paused by only using vanilla JavaScript. I have tried implementing an if-else statement which seems to be commonly used for this type of functionality, but the icon will only change to the "||" icon when the song is played, but will not pause and change to the play icon when clicked again. I have tried creating a separate function for the task of pausing the song, but still not getting the desired result.

```js
var playButton = document.querySelector('#play-button');
    var songArtist = document.querySelector('.song-artist');
    var songTitle = document.querySelector('.song-name');
    var stateIcon = document.querySelector('#stateicon');

    var trackList = [ {
        'Songartist': 'Artist1',
        'Songtitle': 'Dance',
        'songfile': 'Dance.mp3'
    },
    {
        'Songartist': 'Artist2',
        'Songtitle': 'Fight',
        'songfile': 'Battle.mp3'
    }
    ];
    var currentSong = 0;
    var song = new Audio();



    function playSong() {
        song.src = trackList[currentSong].songfile;

        songArtist.innerText = trackList[currentSong].Songartist;

        songTitle.innerText = trackList[currentSong].Songtitle;

        if (song.paused) {
            stateIcon.className = 'fas fa-pause';
            song.play();
        }   else {
            stateIcon.className = 'fas fa-play';
            song.pause();
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="screen">
            <div class="song-info-text">
                    <p class="song-artist">Some text</p>
                    <p class="song-name">Some more text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="mp3-buttons">
                <button class="button" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-step-backward"></i></button>
                <button id="play-button" onclick="playSong()"><i  id="stateicon" class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
                <button onclick="nextSong()" class="button" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-step-forward"></i></button>
            </div>
            <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </body>
```

Comment: May you fix the syntax error in the snippet?

Comment: Add a comma after `'Songtitle': 'Fight'` to fix the syntax error

Comment: I'm seeing references to songArtist, songTitle and stateIcon, but I'm not seeing them initialized on that code.

Comment: I have added my initalized variables to the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The snipped provided is incomplete (no element has the class "song-artist", for one). I'd suggest looking at your javascript dev console for any errors, first. Otherwise, it could be that setting the src of your audio element is resetting your audio's play state. You could try only setting the src if it's different from that of the current track.

Comment: I have added missing information to the snippet. I am still new to javascript, so I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on your suggestion a little more.